# Gatling Performance or Load Test - How to configure a simulation to ramp up slowly and hold X amount of time on the peak load

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling, stress-testing, scala-gatling

How can configure a simulation in Java so it slowly ramps requests to the peak and then holds on the peak for X hours?

Our API service has an Autoscaling policy, so it needs a slow ramp-up with requests to allow it to scale in QA environment.

Currently, I used 2 types of simulations (**rampUsers** or **stressPeakUsers**). I am trying to get a combination of both, How can I do that?

```
        setUp(
            productServiceScn.createProduct.injectOpen(rampUsers(81900).during(7200)).protocols(http.product)
        );
```

[image]

OR

```
        setUp(
            productServiceScn.createProduct.injectOpen(stressPeakUsers(81900).during(7200)).protocols(http.product)
        );
```

[image]

**I would like to do, something like this:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `rampUsersPerSec` then `constantUsersPerSec`?

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeLeung , I tried this and it worked. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your need, I would recommend you to use Closed workload model (User controlling), with sample code example (I will assume you don't need to throttle)

***My code below is in Scala, you have to convert it to Java yourself***

```
.inject(
           rampConcurrentUsers(1).to(YourDesireUser).during(UserRampup),
           constantConcurrentUsers(YourDesireUser).during(SteadyLength),
           rampConcurrentUsers(YourDesireUser).to(0).during(UserRampdown)
       )
```

In this block, you will ramp your Concurrent Users, recommend to match YourDesireUser with UserRampup, to have the inject rate at 1 User / second. Note that each User initiated will send requests immediately

Then constantConcurrentUsers will hold them there, at your desired SteadyLength.

Lastly you ramp down, recommend to reach the rate at 1 User / second, for gracefully stopping the user.